# Changing label name from database value java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, user-interface

I have a database table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "AcademicInfo" ("academicid" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "Title" 
CHAR NOT NULL , "Forename" CHAR NOT NULL , "Surname" CHAR NOT NULL , "Role" CHAR NOT NULL,
"Room" CHAR NOT NULL , "Page" CHAR NOT NULL , "Hours" CHAR NOT NULL , "Phone" CHAR NOT NULL,     
"Mobile" CHAR NOT NULL , "Email" CHAR NOT NULL , "Image" BLOB, "Password" CHAR NOT NULL )
```

The following class:

```
public class MainMenu extends JFrame
{
    Academic ac = new Academic();
    Connection conn = JavaConnect.ConnectDB();
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    String sql; 
    ResultSet rs = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form MainMenu
     */
    public MainMenu() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void Update_table()
    {
        try {
            String sqlStatement = "SELECT Title, Forename, Surname, Role FROM AcademicInfo ";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            table_academic.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void table_academicMouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
    {
        try {
            int row = table_academic.getSelectedRow();
            String table_click = (table_academic.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
            String sqlSt = "SELECT * FROM AcademicInfo WHERE Surname='"+table_click+"'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSt);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {
                label_name.setText(""+rs.getString("Surname"));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a problem at 'table_academicMouseClicked'. my aim is when a record has been clicked on a table, it gets the exact surname from the database sets the 'label_name' appropriately but I am getting a java.lang.NullPointerException at that stage. I only have a problem with event handler method and nothing else. what have i done wrong at academicMouseClicked() ?

Comment: Can you paste the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Your database structure says `Surname` is a `CHAR`, not a `String`?

Comment: seems incomplete code ? where is label_name declaration ?

Comment: @MrLoreI was able to set the label before despite being 'CHAR' on another GUI.

Comment: @vels4j everything works just error on that method

Comment: @SwapnilS stacktrace empty :(

Comment: You need to debug -- Which line throws the NPE? What variable is null on the line that throws the NPE? The JLabel? The ResultSet? Otherwise your question is woefully incomplete. And the stacktrace cannot be empty as it at least shows which line throws the NPE and then some.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have initialized `label_name` in the initialize method.

```
label_name = new JLabel();
```

Comment: yes working on netbeans, automatically initialised. even if i replace the `label_name.setText(""+rs.getString("Surname"));` to `System.out.println("Hello");` it doesnt execute. something before it

Comment: fault was at not closing pst, rs each time elsewhere.